# simplementability

Tags: co.combinatorics

A sequence $\ \mathbf a:=(a_0\ldots a_n)\ $ is called a *simquence* $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ there exista a finite simplicial complex $\ K,\ $  of $\ \dim(K)\le n,\ $ such that $\ K\ $ has exactly $\ a_k\ $ of $\ k$-dimensional simplices for each $\ k=0\ldots n$.

> In the case of a simquence, as above, we have $\ n<a_0.\ $ More generally, 
>    $\ a_k\le\binom{a_0}{k+1}\ $ for every $\ k=0\ldots\ a_0-1$.

---

**Q1**   Characterize simquences;

**Q2**   Given an arbitrary integer $\ \alpha,\ $ what is the number $\ \kappa(\alpha\ n) $ of all simquences $\ \mathbf a:=(a_0\ldots a_n)\ $ such that $\ a_0=\alpha?$ The *total* case of $\ \kappa(\alpha):= \kappa(a_0\ldots a_{_{a_0-1}})\ $ is of a special interest.

**Q3**   Let $\ \mathbf a:=(a_0\ldots a_n)\ $ and $\ |A_0|=a_0.\ $ What is the number $\ S(\mathbf a)\ $ of all complexes $\ K\ $ such that $\ A_0\ $ is the set of the 0-simplices of $\ K?$

**Q4**   What is the maximum $\ S_n\ $ of all $\ S(\mathbf a)\ $ taken over all possible simquences $\ \mathbf a:=(a_0\ldots a_n)\ $ with the given fixed $\ n;\ $ i.e. which simquences allow for a maximal number of simplicial implementations.

Answer (score 5):

The keyword to search for is *$f$-vector*. In Q1 you are asking for a characterization of the possible $f$-vectors of finite simplicial complexes. There is an elegant complete answer which is called the *[Kruskal-Katona theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Katona_theorem)*.